# can 'whose' refer to a thing?

Tags: grammaticality, relative-pronouns

Consider the following two sentences:

> 1. From a roof cluster, the longest gutter line of each face is selected
>      if its height fall into a certain height range.
> 2. The one with the
>      lowest height is taken as the base height.

Can *whose* refer to a thing? As follows:

> From a roof cluster, the longest gutter line of each face and ***whose***
>   height fall into a certain height range is selected and the one with
>   the lowest height is taken as the base height.

Comment: I answered there instead of here.  This is a **relative** use, so the answer is yes.  (In **interrogative** uses of *whose*, the answer is no.)